# EU member extradition

Tags: criminal-law, european-union, extradition

Pretend that a country within the European Union (EU) has refused to extradite somebody, after an extradition request from another country, following a court ruling in the extraditee's favour.

If the, now free, defendant wishes to travel to other EU countries, can they avoid extradition based on the ruling that was in their favour against extradition? Assume the extradition was for the same purposes as the original request for extradition.

My understanding is that EU countries must respect decisions in other EU member courts, so I am guessing this would also apply to extradition.

For the purposes of this question feel free to exclude places such as Norway and Switzerland, as they have their own distinct agreements with the EU.

**EDIT:**
The defendant has a British passport and a Republic of Ireland passport making them dual nationality, however they entered into each EU country using their Irish passport.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in its present form without clarifying whether the defendant is an EU (or EFTA) citizen. See [CJEU Transfers Petruhhin Doctrin to EFTA Nationals - eucrim](https://eucrim.eu/news/cjeu-transfers-petruhhin-doctrin-efta-nationals/).

Comment: The EU might not extradite an Eritrean citizen to Somalia, but the same person still might not be free to move within the EU, due to their Visa or because they are held for immigration reasons.

Comment: @MarkJohnson of course it can “If citizen then x, if non-citizen then y”

Comment: The question has been updated to clarify that they are a dual national with a British and Republic of Ireland passport, however they traveled into the EU and to the next EU country using their Republic of Ireland passport.

Comment: It doesn't matter which passport they used to travel into any country.  The person is an EU citizen under EU law regardless.

Comment: The reason for the denial would matter.

Answer (score 3):

> If the, now free, defendant wishes to travel to other EU countries, can they avoid extradition based on the ruling that was in their favour against extradition?

No. The European Arrest Warrant (EAW) framework does not require a warrant to be withdrawn by the 'requesting country' if a member state decides not to execute it. The EAW remains valid until it is withdrawn by the requesting country.

Scenario:

1. France issues an EAW for Bob.
2. Bob travels to Spain, is arrested and has an extradition hearing where it is decided not to execute the warrant.
3. France does not withdraw the warrant.
4. Bob travels to Portugal - he is not 'safe' from the warrant.

> My understanding is that EU countries must respect decisions in other EU member courts, so I am guessing this would also apply to extradition.

The system has been criticised on that basis. However, on the flip side, the issuing country might want other countries to respect its decision to issue the EAW.

Reference: *[2023 Handbook on how to issue and execute a European arrest warrant](https://commission.europa.eu/document/28199bc3-b431-4d4a-856f-bae681bc8709_en)*:

> 11.3. Consideration by the issuing judicial authorities whether or not to maintain
> the EAW
>
> The Framework Decision on EAW does not require an EAW to be withdrawn if one
> Member State refuses to execute it. This is because other Member States may still be able to execute the EAW. The EAW and corresponding SIS alert therefore remain valid
> unless the issuing judicial authority decides to withdraw it. ...

Comment: The question doesn't mention the European Arrest Warrant at all. I suspect it's about extradition to a third country. Indeed, an EU country wouldn't request an extradition in the first place and most likely use the EAW instead. Even if you want to cover both the European Arrest Warrant and extradition, the answer would be much better if you would clearly distinguish them.

Comment: @Relaxed The European Arrest Warrant replaced the previous extradition agreements between EU member states. Although it might be technically improper to do so, it's common to refer to use of the EAW as extradition, and someone might not know what the EU system is called. Fair point re third countries.

Comment: The thing is that extradition still exists and may in fact be what this question is actually about. It may indeed be common to conflate both but it's much easier to discuss all this using proper terminology.

Comment: Regarding the EAW “replacing” extradition between EU countries, I could not figure out whether that's actually the case, which is why I phrased my comment that way. That's the language used in EU literature and there is no reason not to use the EAW when you can but there are also corner cases (e.g. overseas territories that are not part of the EU territory but do belong to a member state). Even if earlier agreements have actually been rescinded (as opposed to simply becoming moot), extradition doesn't necessarily require an agreement so may theoretically still be possible.

Comment: @Relaxed Perhaps one day the questioner will return to clarify the question. Regardless, I intend to edit when I get a moment. I have three scenarios in mind. One scenario is the use of the EAW for 'surrender' between EU members (commonly but perhaps incorrectly referred to as 'extradition') - as above. Another scenario is a third country seeking extradition of an EU national of a country that refuses to extradite its citizens not in his home nation. Another scenario is a third country seeking extradition of an EU national of a country that does not refuse to extradite its citizens.

Comment: @Lag I thought that the EU had Articles which prevented the person getting tried again in Portugal? Since technically, they would be going to court for the same reason, and we shall safely assume for the same facts.   In accordance with Article 50, the "non bis in idem" principle applies not only within the jurisdiction of one State but also between the jurisdictions of several Member States

Comment: @user5623335 EU Charter of Fundamental Rights, Article 50: "No one shall be liable to be tried or punished again in criminal proceedings for an offence for which he or she has already been finally acquitted or convicted within the Union in accordance with the law." An extradition hearing is not a criminal trial. The hearing is to decide whether to surrender/extradite the person to the requesting country *for* prosecution of a criminal complaint or execution of a sentence. The hearing does not acquit or convict the person.

Comment: @Lag Good point when speaking in general, however in Spain they will conduct the entire trial there as if the crime had happened in Spain, and if the defendant is found not guilty then the extradition is refused. So in the case of Spain, would Article 50 apply?

Comment: @user5623335 I think you are misled about Spain.

Comment: @Lag Maybe I misunderstood this:  In establishing dual criminality, the Judge does not embark upon an assessment of the evidence in the case to determine whether the requesting state has a prima facie case against the requested person (although this may well be an additional requirement in the case of the extradition arrangements with some countries), i.e. whether the individual is likely to be found guilty on the specific facts of the case (R (Castillo) v. King of Spain [2005] 1 WLR 1043). https://www.gherson.com/blog/what-is-dual-criminality-in-extradition/

Comment: @user5623335 The test of 'dual criminality' aka 'double criminality' is whether the conduct alleged to have occurred in the requesting country would be a crime in the surrendering country had it occurred here. The extradition court doesn't determine whether the conduct occurred, it determines whether the conduct would amount to a crime in the court's country if it had occurred.